# css in a chatbox

Tags: html, css

I have a chat program where my target is, when someone type and send a text, i want the text to be display from the bottom. Like any other chating frame.
To do this, i have wrote the following html/css structure.
here the "li" tags are creating dynamically when someone send a text.

The problem:

The problem is if i remove the "height:100% " from the ".chatbox ul", the text in the chatbox starts from the bottom. But in that case i dont see any scroll bar. But I need to see a scroll bar.
And, if I keep the "height:100% " in the ".chatbox ul", I see a scroll bar but the text in the chatbox starts from the top.

My target is to have a scroll bar and the text should also start from the bottom.
How would I acheive this..?? any help guys??

```
<div class="chatBox">
<ul id="messages" class="chatText">
    <li>
    <div class="chatterName">maverick </div>
    <div class="chatterMessage"> hi</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
    
    <li>
    <div class="chatterName">johny</div>
    <div class="chatterMessage"> hello</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.chatBox
{
background-image: url('../images/DefaultitemBg.gif');
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 14px;
color: #333333;
border: 1px double #FFFFFF;
padding: 5px;
margin: 10px;
width:76%;
height:600px;
position:relative;
border: 1px solid #E9E9E9;
overflow:auto;
float:left;

}
.chatBox ul
{
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
position:absolute;
overflow:auto;
bottom:0;
height:100%;
}
.chatBox ul li
{
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-bottom-color: #F2F2F2;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.chatterName
{
width: 120px;
background-color: #EEEEEE;
color: #333333;
float: left;
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-right-color: #CCCCCC;
height: 30px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-bottom-color: #E6E6E6;
}
.chatterMessage
{
width: 91%;
padding-left:4px;
color: #333333;
float:left;
min-height:30px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-bottom-color: #EFEFEF;
}
.chatText
{
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
border-top-style: 0;
border-right-style: 0;
border-bottom-style: 1;
border-left-style: 0;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-bottom-color: #E6E6E6;

width:100%;
```

}

EDIT:

[See it live here](http://screencast.com/t/uXT0rfhue6U7)

If you see carefully, you will notice when i am entering text in the chatbox, from the top, previous texts are disappearing.
What I want is a scroll bar, so that users can see previous messages.

Comment: I cant replicate what you are syaing with the code provided... If you set up a http://jsfiddle.net/ and shared it here we might be able to hep you more. Also, `overflow:scroll;` might be a good idea on the `.chatbox`

Comment: I have edited the question and provided a live video. Hope you will understand the problem better now..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve it:

use `max-height` instead of `height`

```
.chatBox ul
{
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
position:absolute;
overflow:auto;
bottom:0;
max-height: 100%;
/*height:100%;*/
}
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/pt43J/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript to scroll to bottom:

```
document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML += '<li>'+your message here+'</li>'
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)
```